# integration of. $\int \frac{x}{x^3-3x+2}$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I am trying to integrate    :

> $\Large \int \frac{x}{x^3-3x+2}dx$

I decomposed the fraction and got :
$\Large \frac{x}{x^3-3x+2} = \frac {x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$

Then I tried to get two different fractions:
$ \Large \frac {x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)} = \frac {Ax}{(x-1)^2} + \frac {B}{(x+2)}$

Well I got A=1/3 and B=-1/3. as possible values. but that was not correct. I guess I missed something.

Comment: That's not the right rule to use

Comment: try $\dfrac A{x+2}+\dfrac B{x-1}+\dfrac C{(x-1)^2}$

Comment: Alternatively substitute $\frac{x+2}{x-1}=t\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2}=-\frac13 dt$, also $x=\frac{t+2}{t-1}$ so you get $\int \frac{x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}dx=-\frac19\int \frac{t+2}{t}dt$.

Comment: @Zacky  very good intuition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have all the components in the decomposition. It should be

$$\frac {x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)} = \frac {Ax+C}{(x-1)^2} + \frac {B}{x+2}
=\frac {\frac29x+\frac19}{(x-1)^2} - \frac {\frac29}{x+2}$$

Comment: I forgot the rule, now I will never make the mistake again.  Thanks,

Comment: The theory says the numerator has degree less than the *irreducible factor* in the denominator, not less than the denominator itself.

Comment: It should rather be $\frac {\frac29x+\frac{1}{\color{red}9}}{(x-1)^2} - \frac {\frac29}{x+2}$, but ignoring the wrong coefficient I think it's a bad thing to write it like that, since it leads to one more unnecessary step. In order to integrate it we'll have to split again by writting $\frac29(x-1+1)+\frac19$ the numerator.

Comment: @Zachy - thanks for noting it. I'll correct 1/3

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $\frac{Ax}{(x-1)^2}$ you should have
$$\frac A{(x-1)^2}+\frac C{x-1}$$
I get $A=\frac13,B=\frac19,C=-\frac19$.

Comment: @mjw Look at the other answer.

Comment: @mjw Ugh, fine.

Answer (score 1):

When the denominator of a fraction has an irreducible factor $\bigl(p(x)\bigr)^m$ with order of multiplicity $m>1$, its contribution to the decomposition into partial fractions is *not*
$$\frac{A(x)}{\bigl(p(x)\bigr)^m} \qquad (\deg A(x)<\deg p(x)),$$
but
$$\frac{A_1(x)}{p(x)\vphantom{\Big)}}+\frac{A_2(x)}{\bigl(p(x)\bigr)^2}+\dots+\frac{A_m(x)}{\bigl(p(x)\bigr)^m}\\(\deg A_1(x),\deg A_2(x),\dots,\deg A_m(x)<\deg p(x)) $$
Therefore here, as the irreducible factors have degree $1$, the decomposition has the form
$$\frac{x}{x^3-3x+2} = \frac {x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+2}.$$

*Addendum*:

Here is the short way to determine the coefficients: multiply both sides of the above equality by $(x-1)^2(x+2)$ to obtain the relation
$$x=(x-1)(x+2)A+(x+2)B+(x-1)^2C.$$
Setting $x=1$, then $x=-2$, yields instantly
$B=\frac 13$ and $C=-\frac29$. To obtain $C$, observe that the r.h.s. must have no quadratic term, so $A+C=0$ and finally $A=\frac29$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ I=\int \frac{x}{x^3-3x+2}dx$$
$$I= \int \frac {xdx}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$$
Since $\frac {-1}{(x-1)^2}$ is an obvious derivative substitute $$u=\dfrac {1}{x-1} \implies -du=\dfrac {dx}{(x-1)^2}$$
The integral becomes:
$$I=-\int \dfrac {u+1}{3u+1}du$$
Which is easier to integrate. 
$$u+1=u+\frac 1 3 +\frac 2 3$$